# How to add datagridview row "headers"?

Tags: datagridview

How do you do this in datagridview of visual studio?

[image]

any answers are appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `DataGridView` you can:

- create a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` with [`.Frozen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.frozen(v=vs.110).aspx) = `True` and `.ReadOnly = True`
- programmatically create a `DataSet` with 7 fixed rows and set `.AllowUserToAddRows = False` and `.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False`